# Crash dump for bluescreen bccode 50, probably caused by ntoskrnl.exe. Request for minidump analysis

Tags: windows-7, bsod

Approximately a week ago I decided to overclock a bit my CPU. I did everything according the manuals and the internet knowledge. Sadly yesterday I had a persisting problem - when I was turning on the computer my monitor didn't wake up from standing by mode. Fix for that was restart which was bringing everything back to normal. Today I experienced major problem when was listening to music on iTunes. Appeard BSOD. Loading bios defaults didn't work. It seems that something is corrupted.

Below I paste my crash dump file. 
http://www.speedyshare.com/9Tj4f/123114-26551-01.dmp

Also FYI, temperatures were monitored and everything was alright - CPU -+ 45*C in stress, GPU 71*C in stress.

Here are my specs:
Asus P5K
C2D 7300 @ 3.0 ghz, vcore 1,28V
OCZ Platinium Rev. 2 4GB 800mhz 4-4-4-15 vcore 2.1V
Seagate 7200.10 320GB
Chieftec GPS-450A

I will be really grateful for your support, because it is the second time this year, even though I changed my cpu.

Comment: I get an error loading this dump file in my VS. This may be a driver problem. Is there a driver mentioned in the bluescreen?

Comment: The dump file loaded for me in WinDBG (Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.3.9600.17237 AMD64).

Comment: Try using Microsoft's DebugDiag tool. It can analyze the dump file for you.

Comment: First of all - thanks for your interest. I did !analyze -v, but I can't read the result to be honest. I says too many things, and I don't even know which one is the proper one.

Comment: how often do you register here again as a new user every 3 months and ask the same question? Your CPU is damaged because of your overclocking!! Buy a new PC and never do any OC again.

Comment: The problem is that it is a new CPU (not E4300 like earlier, but E7300). Ant the nature of the problem this time is different. I choosed this forum again, because I know that people here are helpful and smart. BTW. at the end of my original post I mentioned that. So should I understand that once helped I have to search for help somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

That's a minidump file, and not going to be enough information to go on in a case like this.
I suggest you stop the over-clocking, as [this can cause instability](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/04/12/407562.aspx) like you describe.

The faulting symbol/fault bucket of *KiGeneralProtectionFault* does [seem](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2276226/bsods.html) [to](http://www.overclock.net/t/1414667/bsod-caused-by-ntoskrnl-exe-driver-verifier-enabled) [coincide](http://forums.overclockers.co.uk/showthread.php?t=18257714) [with](http://www.bluegartr.com/threads/95995-Help-Me-Overclock!/page2) [overclocking](http://forums.extremeoverclocking.com/showthread.php?t=371305).

Comment: Sadly, when I brought everything back to default bios setting, the problem still occures and that's what makes me confused.